# What is the cause of this problem with CONVERT()?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Consider the following two statements:

```
PRINT CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 0), 0x0100000001, 0);
PRINT CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 0), 0x0100010001, 0);
```

Both statements return `-1`; isn't that incorrect since the second binary value is decimal 65,536 higher than the first value, is it not?

Surely this cannot be due to silent truncation?

If I run the following statements:

```
PRINT CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 0),   0x00000001, 0);
PRINT CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 0),   0x00010001, 0);
```

I am presented with the following error:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varbinary to numeric.
```

How can I diagnose what is happening here?

I'm running this on SQL Server 2012, v11.0.5058.  The results are the same on SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2, SQL Server 2005, and SQL Server 2000.

I am attempting to determine if you could use a `BINARY(5)` column as a numeric primary key value of 40 bits.

Comment: The first byte is scale (0x01 = 1), The second byte is precision (0x00 = 0), The final byte is the value (0x01 = 1). Not sure what bytes three and four are for. The sign is in there but that doesn't need two bytes. Certainly flipping that bit doesn't seem to have affected anything.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) says: "Do not try to construct binary values and then convert them to a data type of the numeric data type category".

Comment: It appears from Martin's comment that I *could* use a `BINARY(7)` column to store 40 bits; but what would be the point of that?  That's only a 12.5% savings over using a `BIGINT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decimal and whole numbers are encoded very differently in varbinary. Decimals need more space. Try:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(32), 1), CONVERT(VARBINARY(32), 1.0);
```

In order to return the correct result, you'd need to convert the varbinary value to an `int`, first, as in:

```
PRINT CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 0),   convert(int, 0x00000001), 0); 
PRINT CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 0),   convert(int, 0x00010001), 0);
```

The above print statements return `1` and `65537` respectively.

As for your ultimate goal, storing whole numbers as varbinary to save space, I think you've answered that question yourself - not worth it.